# How to make async API calls with rate limit for a particular timespan?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, server, hapi.js

I am working on project in which I have to make almost 500+ calls in one go from my NodeJS server to third party server. The problem is that third party server has a limit of maximum 50 calls in a second. Can you please help me to implement the logic for making only specified number of calls in one second. The technology/language used in my project is NodeJS with HapiJS framework.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So 500 calls but 50 shall go through, what should happen with the rest 450?

Comment: If there are 500 calls then it should send 50 in one second. Same should happen for next 9 seconds. I mean it should be batch calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use async.js [eachlLimit](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.eachLimit) with desired delay and simultaneous connections. It would be like:

```
async.eachLimit(['ur11','ur12','ur13' /*and so on*/], 50/* how many simultaneous requests*/,  function (url, callback) {
    request(url, /*params*/ function(err, result){
        //handle err and result
        setTimeout(callback, 100 /*you desired delay*/)  

    })    
}, function (err) {
    // all requests done
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this great solution. I was looking for same solution.